# What is the difference between the "mit" and "mit-license" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, licensing

I noticed there are [mit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit) and [mit-license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit-license), but (as both the tags don't have a description) I am not sure I understand when to use one, and when to use the other one. As I noticed there are [gpl](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl) and [lgpl](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgpl), I thought that the tag for the MIT license should be [mit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit); when I entered "mit," the autocomplete proposed me both [mit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit) and [mit-license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit-license).

What is the difference between those tags, or between [bsd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd) and [bsd-license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd-license)?

Answer (score 4):

Probably just a case of mistagging. I'm looking at the licensing tags and they're a mess.

I'll see about coming up with a clean-up suggestion. I think something like "license-X" would work well, cause it'll support wildcards in tag favourites, but for now I'd say it doesn't matter which one you use and we'll settle on an approach in a couple days.

Comment: I wonder if [licensing] + [gpl] and [licensing] + [mit] might work -- software licensing is a really important concept for programmers that almost transcends specific license "types"

Comment: @Jeff I like that in principle, but I think it might be difficult to expect/enforce appropriate tagging in that case, since posters will need to think of adding two tags. I'll throw it in my (upcoming) meta post on licensing tags as an option, though, and see if it flies.

Comment: I think there is no need for two separated tags, if [tag:mit] only refer to the license; if [tag:mit] could have two different, but correlated meanings, then I would agree on using [tag:mit] together with [tag:licensing].