# I'd like to add a licensing tag to a number of Meta questions

Tags: discussion, tags, licensing

Because software licensing is explicitly mentioned in the help center. I think we should have a Meta tag for questions about this issue. Here are some questions that I think would benefit from such a tag:

- [Question regarding license violation?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6186/question-regarding-license-violation)
- [Are software license questions acceptable?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/are-software-license-questions-acceptable)
- [Software Law definition](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/software-law-definition)
- <strike>[What is the difference between the "mit" and "mit-license" tags?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mit-and-mit-license-tags)</strike>
- [Would a "how to choose the best OSS license"-type question be appropriate for PSE?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/would-a-how-to-choose-the-best-oss-license-type-question-be-appropriate-for-ps)
- [Can we put "Software Licensing Questions are off-topic" in the FAQ?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/can-we-put-software-licensing-questions-are-off-topic-in-the-faq/5964#5964)

I would be happy to go ahead and edit such a tag into all of these meta questions (and others I have yet to find), but I thought I'd run it by the community first.

Comment: I closed the "mit" and "mit-license" question since we merged and synonym'd the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) to the following questions:

- [Question regarding license violation?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6186/question-regarding-license-violation)
- <strike>[Are software license questions acceptable?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/are-software-license-questions-acceptable)</strike>
- [Software Law definition](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/software-law-definition)
- <strike>[What is the difference between the "mit" and "mit-license" tags?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mit-and-mit-license-tags)</strike>
- [Would a "how to choose the best OSS license"-type question be appropriate for PSE?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/would-a-how-to-choose-the-best-oss-license-type-question-be-appropriate-for-ps)
- [Can we put "Software Licensing Questions are off-topic" in the FAQ?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/can-we-put-software-licensing-questions-are-off-topic-in-the-faq/5964#5964)
- [Reconciling "no legal advice" and "yes software licensing"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/reconciling-no-legal-advice-and-yes-software-licensing)
- ["How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?" - canonical dupe for license shopping?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/how-can-i-compare-and-contrast-open-source-licenses-canonical-dupe-for-lice)
- [What is the difference between software licensing and copyright](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/what-is-the-difference-between-software-licensing-and-copyright)
- [Are software law questions off-topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/are-software-law-questions-off-topic-here)
- [Discussion on if questions about EULA's are on topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/discussion-on-if-questions-about-eulas-are-on-topic)

There were some other questions that were tagged [legal](/questions/tagged/legal) but they weren't strictly about licensing, so I didn't tag them.